# How do I increment and save a int value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Im trying to keep track of how many times the user loses in my game. So for every loss it goes up by 1. I also want to save it too so the user could see how many total times they lost. Right now the code I have it works the first time and goes to one but if I lose in the game after that it just stays at 1. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
 class level1: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

      var deathScore = 0


      override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

      var deathLabel = SKLabelNode()

      deathLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "LadyIce-3D")
      deathLabel.text = "100"
      deathLabel.zPosition = 14
      deathLabel.fontSize = 100
      deathLabel.fontColor = SKColor.darkTextColor()
      deathLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 1.1, self.size.height / 1.4)
      deathLabel.hidden = true
      self.addChild(deathLabel)

      }



  if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && fourthBody.categoryBitMask == GameOverCategory {


    deathScore++
    deathLabel.hidden = false

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults()

        let saveDeaths = NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("saveNumberOfDeaths")
        if(deathScore > saveDeaths)
        {
            NSUserDefaults().setInteger(saveDeaths, forKey: "saveNumberOfDeaths")
        }
        var showNumberOfDeaths = defaults.integerForKey("saveNumberOfDeaths")




    deathLabel.text = String(showNumberOfDeaths)

     }

     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a new var deathScore everytime, initialized with 0 and incrementing it. It will always be 1.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "saveNumberOfDeaths")+1, forKey: "saveNumberOfDeaths")

deathLabel.text = String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "saveNumberOfDeaths"))
```

Comment: if you post the relative code i can try to help you. See the update

Comment: Im still getting 1....its not changing when I lose again and again. Its stuck on 1 for some reason. I posted the full code in the op I don't have anything else.

Comment: you are assigning 0 to deathScore everytime

Comment: so I have to set it as 1?

Comment: move deathScore to GameViewController class

Comment: just leave deathScore++ there and declare you deathScore at the first line inside class GameViewController: UIViewController {

Comment: NSUserDefaults().setInteger(saveDeaths, forKey: "saveNumberOfDeaths" is wrong !!! Look at my code. You need save deathScore not saveDeaths

Comment: I made sure your code matches and it still gives me a 1 everytime I lose.

Comment: sorry for being a pain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80497/discussion-between-coding22-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: I would create a `var saveNumberOfDeaths: Int` with `getter` and `setter` doing the access to `UserDefaults`. It would be much easier to use.